# module vs package, module and package

Tags: raku

I'm looking for some cleanup of my knowledge. Within a project with complex module structure I'd like to keep the structure clean by building up structured namespace tree. Say, something like:

```
App
  Config
    Key
    Node
    Param
    Type
      MyType
```

Every entry under App::Config shall be contained in its own file. Always typing things like `App::Config::Key` is a time waste. `is export` doesn't have a parameter to declare the name which is to be exported. So, I finally came to the following solution:

*Config.pm6*:

```
unit module App::Config:ver<0.0.1>;
...
```

*Key.pm6*:

```
unit package App::Config;

class Key is export {
    ...
}
```

And it works as I want it:

```
use App::Config::Key;

say Key.^name; # App::Config::Key
```

The only question remains: a there any caveats? Any hidden side effects to know about?

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now, is that you should **not** make the class a `my` if you want to ensure any `.perl` output will round-trip.  It will default to `our`, so if you don't specify anything, you should be find in that respect.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is related to documentation. You will need to know in advance that in order to get to the documentation of Key you need to look up App::Config. Also, documentation of the class itself. It might not be obvious, looking at the file structure, what classes are there available. None of them is a big deal.

Comment: @jjmerelo, do I get you correctly that `p6doc App::Config::Key` will have trouble finding the docs in `App/Config/Key.pm6` in this case?

Comment: @VadimBelman Hum, I didn't understand you correctly. I though that you had a simple App::Config and then you were declaring class Key (and the rest) in the same file. Anyway, answering your question, I don't really know. It's probably not expected, but who knows...

Comment: Ok, it seems like exporting roles from packages doesn't work the way it should. The short name is available, it is applicable to a class. But when tested for `.^does` (or `~~` for that matter) the short names fails the test whereas FQN passes it ok: for `class Foo does Role { ... }` check `Foo ~~ Role === False` but `Foo ~~ App::Config::Role === True`. Would have to report the issue.

Comment: Please do!  and leave a link here so people could follow up on it in the future.

Comment: Done so in a couple of hours after posting the comment: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2617

Answer (score 0):

Far as I can tell, the only problem seems to be you will only be able to recursively declare modules that way. Only one, at the top level, will be possible. See this (simplified) example:

lib/Packr/U/Packd.rakumod:

```
unit package Packr::U;

our class Pack'd is export {}
```

lib/Packr/U.rakumod:

```
unit module Packr::U;
```

lib/Packr/Packd.rakumod:

```
unit package Packr;

our class Pack'd is export {}

our class B::Pack'd is export {}
```

lib/Packr.rakumod:

```
unit module Packr::U;
```

And then the main program:

```
use Packr;
use Packr::U;

for (Packr::Pack'd Packr::B::Pack'd Packr::U::Pack'd ) -> \P {
    say P.new().raku;
}
```

This fails in the last iterated class:

```
Could not find symbol '&Pack'd' in 'Packr::U'
```